# Best approach for Server Sent Events with PHP - Performance Advice

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, server-sent-events

I need some advice on performance...

We have a long running PHP script (could potentially take over 10 mins) with progress updates firing back to the UI via Server Sent Events. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Its all running fine, but I'm worried about it hammering the DB.

The rough flow is this;

> 1) A user goes to the 'publish' page of the app.
>
> 2) The UI opens an EventSource stream to a php script that monitors if
>   a publish is in progress, and reports progress events back if so - checks every
>   second.
>
> 3) If the user initiates a publish, it fires a Ajax call to the long
>   running php script.
>
> 4) The EventSource will then report events back for this publish.

The monitoring is done by storing progress in a mySQL table. 
The long running script writes progress to the DB, and the Event script checks this every second.

As I said, it all works, except that it's hitting the database every second for a look up - for every page left open on the publish page.

It is a low user (sub 100 at the moment - but this could increase), low frequency application, so unlikely there will be more than a hand full on that page at the same time, but still - it doesn't take much.

It's all hosted on AWS - micro DB at the moment.

So I suppose my questions are.

> 1) Hitting the DB every second for each publish page session - is this
>   bad? should I be worried?
>
> 2) What are the alternatives to hitting the DB - write to a file or memory instead ?
>   (bad if we ever load balance)
>
> 3) There is no way to get the PHP event script notified when mySQL
>   table updates is there?

If I extend it to more then a second, the UI progress is pretty lame (skips too much info).

I could dynamically change the update time.  Every second when a publish is in progress, drop down to every 5 or 10 when its not?

Re writing in Node or using a seperate notification server is not really an option - I just want simple progress events for a long running script!!

Any advice much appreciated.

m

Comment: Hitting your db every seconds? very very very bad idea

Comment: Your use case sounds so much like [Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)

Comment: @meda - thats what I thought.  So, it sounds like SSE are pretty much pointless on a PHP based server due to the lack of event loop.  So, any other alternative approaches to this....

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Hitting the DB every second for each publish page session - is this bad? should I be worried?

This will probably kill your DB quick if your user base grows.

> 2) What are the alternatives to hitting the DB - write to a file or memory instead ? (bad if we ever load balance)

File would be easiest.  Although you could potentially use SQLite and take your primary database out of the equation for this particular issue.

> 3) There is no way to get the PHP event script notified when mySQL table updates is there?

Sure there is, in a roundabout way.  Have the event script listen for changes to a cache file that gets written to whenever your MySQL database updates.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  what i suspected, can't really see the point of SSE on php!!  Re the cache file idea - is that not just the same as checking a txt file for changes?  But it's written to when the DB updates?

Comment: @MattBryson Yeah, it's the same thing as checking a text file for changes.  The idea behind doing it that way is that you avoid a db connection for every request.  A more common* way of doing it is to use a caching layer (memcache, redis, etc) between your application and db that periodically persists changes to the database.  That way you're avoiding db connections for every request and reducing the need to implement a message queue system.

*Based on my experience